# GPG error in Ubuntu 21.04 after second apt-get update during Docker build

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gpg-signature

Getting error while building the following Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl=7.\* && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y unzip=6.\* &&\ 
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && \
    mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y maven=3.6.3-5 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

The error occurs when the second `apt-get update` runs.

The error is as follows :-

```
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease' is not signed.
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Confirmed -- I get the same error with that dockerfile, so it's not specific to you.

Comment: I don't know if the bug is actually fixed.  I had the same problem with a ubuntu 21.04 image downloaded a few weeks ago. Tonight I tried wiping to get the ubuntu image re-downloaded and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's a bug in the docker / seccomp / glibc interaction: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1916485

Comment: Fixed in with `runc 1.0.0-rc93`. You could find your version with `docker version`.

Comment: From the [21.04 release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-notes/19221): “Due to changes in glibc 2.33 Ubuntu 21.04 container images require updated container runtimes.
All widely used container runtimes shipped in supported versions of Ubuntu have been updated via the standard stable release updates procedure.
Container hosts running other operating systems may need manual updates.”

Comment: I found I had to completely uninstall docker and re-install to get this to work- following the instructions in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230248/docker-problems-in-ubuntu-20-04 - when using ubuntu 20.04 as the host OS.

Comment: No way to use that fix on Dockerhub yet, right?

Comment: Note: minikube still (as of v1.19.0) has `runc 1.0.0-rc92` and is still effected by this issue (in my case I was using skaffold which does the build in minikube's docker).

Comment: @lewis That worked for me. You might consider posting that as an answer to this question.

Comment: I'm running ARM-based containers. Upgrading to version 1.0.1 of runc fixed this issue for me for the Arm64 container but not for the Arm32 container. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libseccomp/+bug/1916485/comments/59

Answer (score 4):

I've run your docker file and get the same error. Playing around with various ways to disable the verification also produced no good results. Neither did removing the version constraints and just installing the latest versions of the tools. The only solution I could find was to downgrade ubuntu to 20.04, but there is no 3.6.3-5 version of maven for that version of the OS, only 3.6.3-1 (afaik).

The closest I could get working is quite different from your desired image:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update && \
    apt install --no-install-recommends -y curl=7.\* unzip=6.\* maven=3.6.3-1 && \
    apt clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
```

Also note how I use `apt` rather than `apt-get` and I only do a single run (which makes a simpler image by having only a single layer) and only a single `apt update` and chain the things I want to install into a single `apt install` rather than separate ones. This is just quicker and easier.

However, if you want a maven build box, perhaps you'd be better advised using one of the prebuilt maven images from docker hub that are themselves based on openjdk images. For java the underlying linux distro rarely matters and the openjdk images are pretty well respected:

```
from maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
run apt update && apt install -y curl unzip && apt clean
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue with Ubuntu 20.04 is that the security analysis fails for it. (i am using clair analysis for that). Right now the only solution was to use ubuntu version 20.10.

Comment: The problem with using newer distros for your stated reason is that the vulns often haven't caught up yet, not that they don't exist. I think 20.10 was only released 4 months ago, so it's relatively untested, which could result in a false negative. Better sometimes to patch and justify - not all vulns are valid in a given context

Answer (score 4):

This bug does not occur if using a newer version of Docker (tested with 20.10). If using an older version of Docker, I recommend switching to a previous version of the ubuntu image. I tested ubuntu:20.10 with Docker 19.03 and it worked just fine. This is discussed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1928218

Comment: thx, upgrading from Docker 19.03.5 to 20.10.6 fixed it for me =)

Comment: It does not fix the problem for me (on docker 20.10.0 build 7287ab3) on Macintosh.

Comment: Upgrading to 20.10.8 didn't fix my issue!

Comment: This worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while running apt in a chroot (sd card) where /dev/null was not present. Fixed up with bind mounts of /sys/ /proc/ /dev/ /dev/pts

systemd-nspawn was an easier solution, anyway

Answer (score 0):

Update Docker version to the latest to solve this issue.

For ubuntu users follow these steps:

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh

sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

For others please refer this link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/

Answer (score 0):

I was running to the same problem on Docker Desktop 4.26.1

I was able to solve by running `docker system prune --force` prior to running my build command.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this problem when I was running the Ubuntu 21.04 image under Rootless Docker, but the `apt-get update` command worked fine under the system Docker (invoked via `sudo`).  Since my need was just for a manual test of an environment setup script, I just ran under the system Docker but, depending on your application, that might not be secure.

Answer (score -4):

Substituting `apt-get` with `apt` has worked for me.